# php implode if only 1 result

Tags: php, implode

I am using the following to retireve email addresses to auto email after user registration. If there is only 1 result, will the LoadResultArray list correctly in php implode? Or do I have to write an exception if only 1 result?

```
$query = "SELECT u.email FROM " . $table_prefix . "users as u, " . $table_prefix . "bl_teamcord as tc WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$team_id',tc.teams) AND  tc.u_id = u.id AND tc.reg_emails = 1";        
             $db->setQuery($query);
    $remail2 = $db->loadResultArray();


   if ($remail2){
$remail3 = implode(",",$remail2);
}else{
$remail3 = "";}
```

additionally, could there be a problem with the email function?

```
    $to = $remail3;
```

Comment: What would you expect the "correct" result to be? And what about simply trying it?

Comment: Have you tried it? I mean, you can just put the code in a PHP file, run it and see what happens. You have a development environment don't you? It'll probably be quicker than asking a question about it...

Comment: @netcoder +1 Even if you don't have a development environment, you could easily just write a literal array with one element and try it.

Answer (score 17):

If it's only 1 element, the delimiter won't be present, so you should have no issues. Additionally, if there are no elements, it'll return an empty string, too, so no need to test.

```
$a = array();
$b = implode(',',$a); // ""

$a = array('foo');
$b = implode(',',$a); // "foo";

$a = array('foo','bar');
$b = implode(',',$a); // "foo,bar";
```

As demonstrated [here](http://ideone.com/wfimf).

Answer (score 0):

implode works for any sized array.

implode(',', array()) === ''

implode(',', array('something')) === 'something'

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, implode will always return a string for an array that is passed in.

When you pass in something that *isn't* an array, though, php will throw a WARNING indicating that the item you just passed was not a valid array...

So to answer your question, this is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT u.email FROM " . $table_prefix . "users as u, " . $table_prefix . "bl_teamcord as tc 
      WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$team_id',tc.teams)
        AND tc.u_id = u.id
        AND tc.reg_emails = 1";
$db->setQuery($query);

$remail2 = $db->loadResultArray();
$remail3 = (!empty($remail2) ? implode(",", $remail2) : "");
?>
```

More information is always available on the PHP manual's website (it's perhaps the best online manual on the net for a programming language.

In the future just remember: if you need to know something about a method, what it does, or how it works, you can find the documentation by following this url format:
http://www.php.net/YOUR_METHOD_CALL_HERE

In your case: http://www.php.net/implode

The top section of the manual will almost always let you know how cases like the one you just gave will result in if the method is called in proper *and* obscure ways.

hope this helps.